# how to step (walking) on HTML node tree and all sub elements etc?

Tags: javascript, html, tree

We have a need to step the entire tree of HTML elements and check each one for attribute and more.

We have JavaScript solution to move on each HTML element child and all their children. We want a native solution for that. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

OK, we did find a solution! Amazing one, supported in ALL BROWSERS! see the browser support [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker#Browser_compatibility).

[TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) is component native to ALL browser, exist since IE9 (yes!!!), and it just walks inside a tree of elements from Root element you gave it through entire tree and all it sub-elements untile it walking all of them.

hope it helped.